# filePointer automatically progressing in while loop?

Tags: c, file, file-pointer

I am currently getting myself into fileusage in C.
I found a code explaining reading strings from a file. 
However I am really curious how this mechanically works.

```
while (!feof(fPointer)){
fgets(singleLine, 150, fPointer);
puts(singleLine);
}
```

How does the filepointer know at the end of the loop to go for a further line? Shouldnt the filepointer be increased at the end of the while loop?

Cheers

Comment: You need to know more about file seeking and pointer movements. `fgets` function actually moves the file pointer to the next line after reading certain number of characters. In your case `150`

Comment: isn't it `feof()` in `while`?

Comment: yeah sorry about the typo, I will edit it.
so basically the command fgets increases the filepointer automatically?

Comment: If this is the code you found, I suggest you find something else because it's wrong. See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). The correct way to read the file would be: `while (fgets(...)) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you @interjay, couldnt see this topic when searching for it. I will read it carefully and try to understand it in depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `FILE` object stores information about an open file, including a "current positition". Each read/write operation increments the current position by how many bytes were read/written. That's why you can just keep calling `fgets` (or any other input function) in a loop and get the contents, chunk by chunk.

Similarly, you can just call `printf` (or any other output function) multiple times to produce output, and they won't overwrite each other.

You can get and set the current file position using `ftell` and `fseek` (subject to some restrictions, e.g. standard C doesn't require `ftell` to return an actual byte offset on text files, just some "magic number" that can be passed to `fseek` (but I've never seen that in a real implementation)).

(Your `fPointer` just points to one `FILE` object. You shouldn't increment this pointer; it'll just point to random memory.)

Finally, `while (!feof(fp))` is wrong because `feof` queries the "end of file" bit stored in the `FILE` object. It does not predict whether the next read will fail due to reaching the end of the file. The "end of file" bit is only set to true after an input function reaches the end of the file. This kind of loop will run once more after end-of-file and then process garbage (or stale, from the previous iteration) data.